# Is RxKotlin Depend upon RxJava in Android?

Tags: rx-android, rx-kotlin2

Can I use Rx Kotlin + Rx Android without adding Rx Java? Or Rx Kotlin is depended upon Rx Java.

Answer (score 0):

Both Rx Kotlin & Rx Android libraries are extensions on top of Rx-java and so contains Rx-Java by default. Please refer to https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/2.x/rxandroid/build.gradle  & https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin/blob/2.x/build.gradle  for a complete list of dependencies that these two libraries use.